# Meteor 0.3.9 on Windows XP exits with code: -1073741819

Tags: windows-xp, meteor

I have installed recently Meteor 0.3.9 on Windows XP (msi installer from: http://win.meteor.com/) and when I try to run (under CMD):

```
meteor create --example leaderboard
cd leaderboard
meteor
```

I get:

```
[[[[[ C:\temp\leaderboard ]]]]]

Running on: http://localhost:3000/
Exited with code: -1073741819
Exited with code: -1073741819
Exited with code: -1073741819
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried running the following command on directory C:\Program Files\meteor,
where I installed meteor. No luck. Then I tried running the same command on directory

C:\ the main root on my Windows Vista Ultimate. I keyed in **meteor create myapp**

then *myapp* directory is created.

To run your new app, change directory to myapp, (**CD myapp**) then type **meteor**, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Go to your browser and type **localhost:3000**
and voila! You will be able to see "Hello World!"

Try not running it on directory *temp*.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help me. But thanks for suggestion!